How to remove data from mongo dab using $pull operator
i am new in the field mern stack and i want your help to remove to remove comment from User data which is equal to Post data comment
Post Data: {
  _id: new ObjectId('66985b5774dd3a87fd1be9d4'),
  title: 'adadasd',
  description: 'adasda',
  category: 'Web Development',
  user: new ObjectId('6692abbc21ab34ea540b3755'),
  role: 'Blogger',
  bio: 'Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.',
  comments: [
    {
      _id: new ObjectId('66985b6074dd3a87fd1be9dc'),
      user: new ObjectId('6692abbc21ab34ea540b3755'),
      message: 'adad',
      post: new ObjectId('66985b5774dd3a87fd1be9d4'),
      createdAt: 2024-07-18T00:01:36.508Z,
      updatedAt: 2024-07-18T00:01:36.508Z,
      __v: 0
    },
    {
      _id: new ObjectId('66985b6374dd3a87fd1be9e4'),
      user: new ObjectId('6692abbc21ab34ea540b3755'),
      message: 'dada',
      post: new ObjectId('66985b5774dd3a87fd1be9d4'),
      createdAt: 2024-07-18T00:01:39.457Z,
      updatedAt: 2024-07-18T00:01:39.457Z,
      __v: 0
    }
  ],

User data: {
    _id: ObjectId('66985b5774dd3a87fd1be9d4'),
    title: 'adadasd',
    description: 'adasda',
    category: 'Web Development',
    image: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/dgmfnfvf9/image/upload/v1721260913/blog-app-v3/ty1qyrqyodklxqwmf7us.jpg',
    user: ObjectId('6692abbc21ab34ea540b3755'),
    role: 'Blogger',
    bio: 'Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.',
    comments: [
      ObjectId('66985b6074dd3a87fd1be9dc'),
      ObjectId('66985b6374dd3a87fd1be9e4'),
      ObjectId('66985f4746d06f903adef17f'),
      ObjectId('66986298273a46211122814c')
    ],
    createdAt: ISODate('2024-07-18T00:01:27.733Z'),
    updatedAt: ISODate('2024-07-18T00:32:24.142Z'),
    __v: 0
  },

and the code i am trying to run  is
app.post('/remove',async (req,res,next)=>{
    try {
        const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id,{
            comments: 1,
            _id: 0
        });
        //if post is deleted then remove post id from user post
        await User.updateOne({post: req.params.id},{
            $pullAll: {
                comment: {$in: post.comments}
            },
            
        });
    } catch (error) {
         return res.render("posts/postDetails",{
            error: error.message,
            post: ""
        });
    }
});

I just want to remove Comment of User data whose id is equal to Post Data

I think that a few errors/things that need to be clarified in your question.

There is no post field in the User document. So your update query will never work. Your Post and User data are odd as they refer to the same ID. This makes the relationship become 1-to-1, by right a user can post multiple posts and a post is only created by one user (1-to-many, ignore nowadays Facebook, Instagram platforms support feature with one post can have multiple (associate) post owner).
I leave here to let you re-think your implementation of the relationship between the User and Post collections.
The actual correct way should be when the post is deleted:
1.1. Get its user values in the comments array.
1.2. Fetch the User documents by the value from (1.1).
1.3. Update the User documents for the comments array field by pulling the element(s) based on the comments' _id field from the deleted post.

The post.comments returns an array of objects, while you can't use it in the $pullAll operator for the comments (typo error in your query) array in the User document, as the comments is an array of ObjectIds. They are different types.


From $pullAll documentation:

$pullAll removes elements that match the listed values.

For the fixes:

Change the post field to _id for referring based on your current implementation.

Provide the comment's _id array to the comments array for the $pullAll operator


await User.updateOne({ _id: req.params.id}, {
  $pullAll: {
    comments: post.comments.map(x => x._id)
  }
});

Demo @ Mongo Playground
